# Node Js .get() requires callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my server.js code

```
    var express = require('express');
feeds = require('./routes/whatshappeningfeed');
var http = require('http');
var pathname = require('path');

// Test services - to be removed
courses = require('./routes/courses'); 
auth = require('./routes/auth');
token = require('./routes/token');

var app = express();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
  if (!error) {
    next();
  } else {
    console.error(error.stack);
    res.send(500);
  }
});

app.get('/me/whatshappeningfeed',feeds.getfeeds);
app.get('/courses', courses.findAll);
app.get('/courses/:id', courses.findById);
app.get('/token', token.auth);
app.get('/auth', auth.auth);
app.get('/refresh', auth.refresh);

app.listen(80);
console.log('Listening on port 80...');
```

this is my error message :

```
F:\NODE.JS\poc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:291
    throw new Error(msg);
          ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at F:\NODE.JS\poc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:291:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Router.route (F:\NODE.JS\poc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:287:13)
    at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (F:\NODE.JS\poc\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:318:16)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (F:\NODE.JS\poc\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:431:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\NODE.JS\poc\server.js:44:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

When i run the node server.js file i got above error. it was working earlier. i couldn't sort out the issue. please anyone help me.

Comment: It's hard to see inside your routes from this piece of code. And can you define what means "it was working earlier"?

Comment: How about some elementary debugging here to figure out which route is causing you a problem?  Either remove them all and insert one at a time or put `console.log()` statements between them or step through their initialization in the debugger.  This is called elementary software troubleshooting.  The tools exist to take a methodical approach to figuring out which route(s) are causing a problem and why.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, app.get() requires a callback function. So it means that one or more of your routes are missing a callback.

ALL of your routes should have a function(req,res), whether explicitely as in the example or in another function (see comments) :

```
app.get('/me/whatshappeningfeed', function(req,res){ //request, response
     //then here you can define what your server should send as a response when queries for /me/whatshappeningfeed
     res.send(feeds.getfeeds()); //this will send back to the browser the result of feeds.getfeeds()

});
```

Also, not sure if it's due to the copypaste you did, but the first semicolon `require('express');` should be a comma.

Comment: It depends on how `.getfeeds()` is implemented. It could be that it's implemented as `function (req,res) {...}` in which case the original code is correct.

Comment: true, but one of the routes is obviously not, I'll edit my answer to reflect that, thx for pointing it out